# "Edit Master Slides" in Keynote - disabled

Tags: macros, iwork-keynote

Anyone come across "Edit Master Slides" being disabled ?

Keynote version `7.0.5`

Screenie below.

Many thanks.

[image: screenie]

Comment: Seeing the same thing with a presentation in 7.2.

Answer (score 5):

From the menu screenshot it seems you are sharing the presentation.

I had your problem in Keynote 7.3 and needed to **turn off** Collaboration to re-enable the Edit Master Slides menu item.

Comment: If there are any Mac developers out there, create a bug report and refer to `rdar://42733492` to increase the count on this issue.